# Go set header for all handlers

Tags: go, http-headers

For now it looks like this

```
func cacheHandler(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "max-age=1800")
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
http.Handle("/", cacheHandler(http.FileServer(http.Dir("./template/index"))))
http.HandleFunc("/json", sendJSONHandler)
http.HandleFunc("/contact", contactHandler)
http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", cacheHandler(http.FileServer(http.Dir("./template/static")))))
http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)
```

Is there way to set cache header to all handlers at one time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the mux

```
  http.ListenAndServe(":80", cacheHandler(http.DefaultServeMux))
```

instead of the individual handlers.

Note that `ListendAndServe` uses `http.DefaultServeMux` as the handler when the handler argument is `nil`.  Also, the `http.Handle` and `http.HandleFunc` add handlers to `http.DefaultServeMux`.